# Prove that $\frac{x+1}{x^2 +1} + \sin(x) = 0$ admits at least one solution.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove that $\frac{x+1}{x^2 +1} + \sin(x) = 0$ admits at least one solution.

The way I did this, is to use the Intermediate Value Theorem or Bolzano's Theorem that states that: $\text{Given a continuous function in} \; [a,b] \; \text{and} \; \operatorname{sgn}(f(a)) \neq \operatorname{sgn}(f(b)) \rightarrow \exists \; \text{at least one}\; c \in (a,b) / f(c)=0$

So, I did exactly that, but with a little help from a graph.

$h(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2 +1} + \sin(x)\; \text{continuous} \; \forall x \in \Bbb R \; \text{, in particular} \; \forall x \in [-1,0] \; \text{and} \; \operatorname{sgn}(f(-1)) \neq \operatorname{sgn}(f(0)) \rightarrow \exists \; c \in (-1,0)/ f(c)=0$

The doubt that I have is this. How can I find these values without looking at a graph and without having to do a function analysis? $h(x)$ has many values that satisfy $h(x)=0$. Any other way to resolve the exercise is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mean-value theorem is the best tool to use here. Your proof looks fine. If you want, you can adapt it to show that there is a (countable) infinity of zeros in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also to be clear you mean to say at least one real solution. Because if you extend this to x in the complex then the problem is different and MVT is not an option

Comment: You do not need the exact value of $h(x)$, just the sign. Choose points where $h$ can be easily evaluated, e.g. $0,\pi/2,\dots$.

Comment: What's the problem using MVT? Or Intermediate Value Theorem? I mean, it's a perfectly valid solution. And @Kori real solutions are a subset of complex solutions so in fact this would still suffice

Comment: I'm not saying that it not a valid solution. My problem was (is) picking the values of a and b so they satisfy the theorem. It is not particular to this exercise my doubt but to all exercises that need to use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: I mean, there are probably many solutions to this exercise (some more complicated than others) - but ultimately Intermediate Value Theorem **proves the existence of the root rigorously** and does so simply. It wouldn't be enough, for example, to write "ah yes, when I graph the function on my computer it crosses $0$ therefore the root exists" - this isn't a proof. But actually plugging in values and evaluating it like this does constitute a proof when combined with IVT. Honestly for most exercises, you just need to use intuition to figure a value that may work and just do trial and error

Comment: For example, when I saw this I immediately thought of plugging in $0$ and ${-1}$ - why? Well ${x=-1}$ makes ${\frac{x+1}{x^2 + 1}}$ vanish, and ${0}$ makes ${\sin(x)}$ vanish (there's no reason they **need** to vanish, but it was just a thought) - and I can evaluate both these points rather simply (well, ${\sin(-1)}$ I can't, but we know ${\sin(-1)=-\sin(1)<0}$, which is all that matters. Even ${-\pi}$ and ${0}$ would suffice as well, and this is even easier to evaluate (it causes ${\sin(x)}$ to vanish both times, so we are just dealing with some very simple numbers)

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Thanks. That is really helpfull.

Comment: @Karl no problem whatsoever :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach which you can think of as an extended MVT is using a the [Fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem):
Every continuous function from a closed ball of a Euclidean space into itself has a fixed point

Here your $f(x) =- [\sin(x)(x^2+1) +1]$ and then solving your problem is the same as $f(x) = x$, then all you have to do is argue that $f$ is continues in your open ball ($\Bbb R$). Which is simple because $f$ is composed of polynomial and a trigonometric function. Thus you are done with minimal effort.

Comment: This seems extreme to me. Brouwer's fixed point theorem doesn't add anything when compared to OP's solution: like the MVT it states existence, nothing more. Moreover, for $n=1$, Brouwer's fixed point theorem is a trivial consequence of the MVT (so we're actually going in a circle). For $n>1$ the proof is much harder, and is unnecessary for this exercize.

Comment: Probably, I do not disagree mathematically speaking, but this was the first thing that came to my mind after MVT. Also for MVT I needed to argue change of signs so I had to do some calculation and here I really did not.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=0$ or $n\in \Bbb N$ then $h(3\pi/2+2\pi n)<0<h((2n+2)\pi)$ so $h(x)=0$ for some $x\in (3\pi/2+2\pi n,\,(2n+2)\pi).$